# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have a command that outputs user information. Though most fields have no problems, the Status field is rather buggy for me.

This is the code for the command:

```js
import { Command } from '@sapphire/framework';
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';

export class UserInfoCommand extends Command {
    constructor(context, options) {
        super(context, {
            ...options,
            name: 'userinfo',
            description: 'Retrives user information.',
            aliases: ['user'],
        });
    }

    async messageRun(message, args) {
        const userInfo = await args.pick('member').catch(() => message.member);
        const roleMap = userInfo.roles.cache.mapValues(roles => roles.name);
        const roleArray = Array.from(roleMap.values());

        const userEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Information about ${userInfo.displayName}#${userInfo.user.discriminator}`)
            .setColor(0xC63D85)
            .setThumbnail(userInfo.displayAvatarURL())
            .addField('ID', `${userInfo.id}`, true)
            .addField('Status', `${userInfo.presence.status}`, true)
            .addField('Account Created:', `${userInfo.user.createdAt}`)
            .addField('Joined on:', `${userInfo.joinedAt}`)
            .addField('Server Nickname:', `${userInfo.displayName}`)
            .addField('Server Roles:', `${roleArray.join(', ')}`);
        return message.channel.send({ embeds: [userEmbed] });
    }
}
```

When executing the command with me (or a user offline since the bot was started), it throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')`. When I go online and then offline once again, the command works and outputs offline as my status.

I do have the proper intents enabled.

```
const client = new SapphireClient({
    intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILD_PRESENCES'],
    disableMentionPrefix: true,
    typing: true,
    presence: {
        activities: [
            {
                name: 'Captain\'s commands!',
                type: 'LISTENING',
            },
        ],
    },
});
```

I've tried to use an if statement where if `userInfo.presence.status` is null then it should throw offline instead but that didn't work out. How can I make this work out properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the line with:

```js
.addField('Status', `${userInfo.presence? userInfo.presence.status : "offline"}`, true) // if presence is truthy, output the string, else, the user is offline
```

A simple null check that worked. Probably my previous method was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `PRESENCE INTENT` option enabled in the applications bot settings

This setting is required to get presence updates

Comment: It is enabled https://i.snipboard.io/DIL6Po.jpg